DTExecUI works but DTExec does not
I'm trying to run an SSIS package on a remote workstation located inside a company network because a firewall prevents the ETL servers from communicating directly with each other. Reconfiguring the firewall or installing unapproved software as admin is not currently possible.
I am allowed to install 32-bit SQL Server Management Studio, which does come with DTExec.exe and DTExecUI.exe, so I should be able to run my package. Both DTExec and DTExecUI are 32 bit programs located in Program Files (x86). I am able to run my package in DTExecUI just fine, but DTExec gives me the error

Data Flow objects cannot be loaded. Check if Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineXml.dll is properly registered.

Here is the full output.
C:\scad>DTExec.exe /f Package.dtsx
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 15.0.2000.229 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  11:36:24 AM
Error: 2024-06-20 11:36:24.66
   Code: 0xC0040019
   Source: Data Flow Task Data Flow Task (SSIS.Pipeline)
   Description: Data Flow objects cannot be loaded. Check if Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineXml.dll 
   is properly registered.
End Error
Error: 2024-06-20 11:36:24.66
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: Data Flow Task
   Description: Failed to load task "Data Flow Task", type "SSIS.Pipeline.7". The contact 
   information for this task is "Performs high-performance data extraction, transformation and 
   loading;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights 
   Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".
End Error
Error: 2024-06-20 11:36:24.68
   Code: 0xC001F02A
   Source: Package
   Description: Cannot create a task from XML for task "Execute SQL Task", type 
   "Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask" due to error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".
End Error
Error: 2024-06-20 11:36:24.68
   Code: 0xC0010018
   Source: Execute SQL Task
   Description: Failed to load task "Execute SQL Task", type "". The contact information for 
   this task is "Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; SQL Server 2017; ? 2017 Microsoft 
   Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1".
End Error
Error: 2024-06-20 11:36:24.69
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Data Flow Task
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  11:36:24 AM
Finished: 11:36:24 AM
Elapsed:  0.344 seconds

Things I have tried that haven't worked:

Running DTExec from a 32-bit command line launched with C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe.
Changing the TargetServerVersion in the Configuration Properties.
Setting Run64BitRuntime to False in the Debugging Configuration Properties.
Running dtexec.exe with the active directory set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn in case this was a DLL search path issue.
Using the exact command line produced in the "Command Line" section of DTExecUI.

I know one answer is to install SSIS on the remote workstation, but I can't do that and it's very strange to me that DTExecUI works but DTExec does not with the same file.

Note for production use, to use DTExec the host requires a SQL Server licence.

From this it seems like you need SSIS installed on the server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver16
